# Range marks aren't set in lua function called from keymap

Tags: neovim, lua, mark

I'm trying to insert a table of contents with an external process. Currently, I have this:

#### .config/nvim/after/ftplugin/markdown.lua

```lua
--- @param v boolean
local function toc(v)
  if v then
    vim.cmd([['<,'>d]])
    vim.cmd("w")
  end
  vim.cmd([[ exe 'r!md-toc --indent 2 %' ]])
end
vim.keymap.set("n", "<localleader>T", toc, { desc = "insert toc" })
vim.keymap.set("v", "<localleader>T", function() toc(true) end, { desc = "insert toc" })
```

This works for normal mode, but for visual mode, I get:

```
   Error  13:23:19 msg_show.emsg E5108: Error executing lua: vim/_editor.lua:0: nvim_exec2(): Vim(delete):E20: Mark not set
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'nvim_exec2'
    vim/_editor.lua: in function 'cmd'
    /Users/h4s/commons/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/markdown.lua:4: in function 'toc'
    /Users/h4s/commons/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/markdown.lua:10: in function </Users/h4s/commons/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/markdown.lua:10>
```

I'm not sure why these marks go away when I call the function. How can I have access to the range within the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```lua
--- @param v boolean
local function toc()
  vim.cmd([[ exe 'r!md-toc --indent 2 %' ]])
end
vim.keymap.set("n", "<localleader>T", toc, { desc = "insert toc" })
vim.keymap.set("v", "<localleader>T", ":d<CR>:normal <localleader>T<CR>", {})
```

The problem you have is that the `'<` and `'>` marks are only set after the Visual selection has been cleared.

Comment: I saw somewhere about the range markers not being set until the selection was cleared, so I tried various ways of escaping to address that, without success. But I don't see how you code sample addresses this. So, is `<c-s>` some copypasta from an example. I'm just a bit confused.

Comment: Sorry for the copy paste (I copy the code I tested on my machine where <localleader>T is already mapped to something else :-|). The strategy of the code is to trigger the deletion on the current selection (using `:d`) and then use the Normal mode and the normal mode mapping to insert the table of content.

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes perfect sense now, and is a simpler solution. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)